# Require text after ignoring a specific words using REGEX

Tags: regex

I would like to extract words after ignoring certain key words.

I want to ignore **supplied by**  or **supplied by M/S** until the end of line.

**Input Text**

Remittance Advice

This section includes details as supplied by   M/S MOBIS INDIA LIMITED

This section includes details as supplied by MANDO AUTOMOTIVE INDIA LIMITED

This section includes details as supplied by MAHINDRA AND MAHINDRA AUTO SECTOR

**Expected Output**

MOBIS INDIA LIMITED

MANDO AUTOMOTIVE INDIA LIMITED

MAHINDRA AND MAHINDRA AUTO SECTOR

**I have given something like this**

(?<=(supplied by.)|(supplied by   M/S.)).*

Appreciate help here.

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using? Anyway, `(?:(?<=supplied by M\/S )|(?<=supplied by )).*` will work with any flavor that supports Lookbehinds. Depending on what regex flavor you're using, there might be shorter patterns to achieve the same result.

Comment: Hi, I want to use this in uipath for extracting data from pdf files.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  What are you trying to match after ignoring these words, and why can't you just delete these words from the string before applying the regex?  I believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Hi, There are 2 spaces before M/S which is not getting ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a match only, you can use lookarounds, and optionally match `M/S` in the lookbehind and asserting that when starting the match it is not going to be `M/S`

```
(?<=supplied by\s+(?:M/S\s+)?)\S(?<!\s+M(?=/S\s)).+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `supplied by\s+` Match literally followed by 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:M/S\s+)?` Optionally match `M/S` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\S` Match a non whitespace character
- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind

  - `\s+M(?=/S\s)` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `M` and assert `S` followed by a whitespace char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `.+` Match 1+ times any character

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dsupplied+by%5cs%2b%28%3f%3aM%2fS%5cs%2b%29%3f%29%5cS%28%3f%3c!%5cs%2bM%28%3f%3d%2fS%5cs%29%29.%2b&i=This+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+++M%2fS+MOBIS+INDIA+LIMITED%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+MANDO+AUTOMOTIVE+INDIA+LIMITED%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+MAHINDRA+AND+MAHINDRA+AUTO+SECTOR)

Another way to write it could be matching 1+ non whitespace chars followed by asserting a whitespace boundary to the right, and then assert that directly to the left is not `M/S`

```
(?<=supplied by\s+(?:M/S\s+)?)\S+(?!\S)(?<!M/S).+
```

See another [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dsupplied+by%5cs%2b%28%3f%3aM%2fS%5cs%2b%29%3f%29%5cS%2b%28%3f!%5cS%29%28%3f%3c!M%2fS%29.%2b&i=This+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+++M%2fS+MOBIS+INDIA+LIMITED%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+MANDO+AUTOMOTIVE+INDIA+LIMITED%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+section+includes+details+as+supplied+by+MAHINDRA+AND+MAHINDRA+AUTO+SECTOR)

Another option is to use a capture group instead:

```
\bsupplied by(?:\s+M\/S)?\s+(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAOHu1/1)